# Comparing string in mysql doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, string-comparison

I want to compare strings in mysql, but all what I am doing seems not working correctly.

I have table USERS where login/password are varchars (128 / 255) and one record inside (see below)

[image: msqlrecord]
I wanted to get user where login is quak, and password is 'd08...', so i created some queries:

1. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.password IN ('d08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702');` - Not work
2. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.password = 'd08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702';` - Not work
3. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE strcmp(d.password, 'd08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702');` - Not Work
4. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.login IN ('quak');` - Work
5. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.login = 'quak';` - Work
6. `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE strcmp(d.login, 'quak') = 0;` - work (returned 0 - the same)

   1. Why queries 1,2 aren't working where queries 4,5 are?
   2. Why queries 3 isn't working, when query 6 is working?

My goal is getting an user wher login = .. and password = ..

Text comparing as as utf8 general

Comment: Try `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.password LIKE '%d08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702%' `

Comment: @TravisSmith: `MySql returned empty result (zero records)`

Comment: Experiment with `SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE d.password LIKE '%d08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331‌​d0b70%'` And see if it still returns an empty result

Comment: @TravisSmith: Yep, this works. Do you think, that someone can have similar password, but last char will be different? SHA2 method

Comment: Well it is possible, but not likely if this is a hash. That said, this is very strange I don't see why that would happen.

Comment: @TravisSmith: if you didn't saw my edited comment. it is sha2. I am still waiting for an answer which explain why ' = ' comparer didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134221/discussion-between-travis-smith-and-niewidzialny).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some kind of space/special char?

try:

```
SELECT d.* FROM USERS d WHERE trim(uppercase(d.password)) =  trim(uppercase('d08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702'));
```

Comment: I changed it to `SELECT d . * FROM USERS d WHERE trim( UPPER( d.password ) ) = trim( UPPER( 'd08774a578812218da9f94480f914589e57ff1f358ccfed6009e1d9331d0b702' ) )`

And it still does not work. I checked both strings at textdiif.com - and it says that they are the same

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    SELECT * FROM USERS d WHERE password like 'd08%';
```

Comment: This is good, but what if i will have more users, and some of this new user will have password 'd08123123123123'? It will return both users. And i dont want like that.  Both passwords must be exactly this same